# Isolating values found in grep -A results

Tags: bash, awk, grep

and thanks for the time you take to answer these questions.  I have a phone bill that I would like to process via bash.  I've used grep, awk, and sed to find a few of the values I need, but I'm not sure how to find the rest.  I'm using grep to find this first line of code in the large file, but if there's a better way I'm open to it.  Here is my example.

```
garbage
garbage
Phone usage details for 777-555-1234
garbage
garbage
garbage
Total Long Distance 124.82
garbage
garbage
Total International 23456.01
garbage
garbage
Phone usage details for 777-444-0987
```

I need to grab each total before the next number, then add them, but I can figure that part out.  If I could get results like the following, I'd be happy.

```
Phone usage details for 777-555-1234
Total Long Distance 124.82
Total International 23456.01
```

Thanks in advance for any help or input.

Comment: What do you have up to now?

Comment: The right answer depends entirely on the possible values of the text you have represented by repeated use of the word `garbage` so YMMV with whatever answer you get. Replace "garbage" with some truly representative text if you'd like more help.

Answer (score 0):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
awk '
/Phone usage details for/ && flag{
  printf("%s%s%.2f%s%.2f\n",val,"\nTotal Long Distance ",sum_long,"\nTotal International ",sum_inter);
  sum_long=sum_inter=""
}
/Phone usage details for/{
  val=$0;
  flag=1;
  next
}
flag && /Total Long Distance/{
  sum_long+=$NF;
  next
}
flag && /Total International/{
  sum_inter+=$NF
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Phone usage details for 777-555-1234
Total Long Distance 124.82
Total International 23456.01
```

Answer (score 0):

All is here to learn but the OP must tell what he try before you give him a solution like say by 123.
So with sed.

```
sed -n '/Phone/{h;:A;n;/Total/!bA;H;:B;n;/Total/!bB;H;x;p}' infile
```

Comment: This works the best so far.  It's a pdf file, so I must use
    less infile | sed

What if there are more than two totals?  In any of the sections, there may be up to 5 totals.  I appreciate the input.

Comment: I don't understand why must use less. You can try this new one : `sed -n '/Phone/{$p;h;:A;${x;p};n;/Phone/{x;p;x;h;bA};/Total/!bA;H;bA}' infile`